# Custom View: Setting visibility to GONE not working as expected

Tags: android

I've created a custom view, seen below. I declare this custom view in other xml files. The issue I'm having is that when I call

> MyVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE)

The video that was previously drawn on the SurfaceView is still visible. Shouldn't setting the visibility of the whole View affect the children? Am I missing something?

```
public class MyVideoView extends FrameLayout {

    private SurfaceView videoSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceView subtitleSurfaceView;

    public MyVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context) {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.widget_my_video_view, this);

        videoSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.svPlaybackSurface);
        subtitleSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.svSubtitles);
    }    
}
```

widget_my_video_view.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/svPlaybackSurface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/svSubtitles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paddingRegular"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/paddingRegular"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/paddingLarge"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Don't you need to do:
`LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_my_video_view,this);`

Comment: View.Inflate is a convenience method. it's the same as calling LayoutInflater.from(context)...

Comment: Have you tried to replace it by this code?

Comment: I've used that code in the past. The problem is not that the view doesn't inflate. It's that it won't hide when the custom parent View is hidden.

Comment: When the custom parent is invisible all the subviews are invisible.

Comment: I'm not sure you get what I'm asking for, but humor me.

Comment: Because either directly or indirectly you are making it Visible somewhere else